# How to replace substrings that contain any integer in java?

Tags: java, regex, substring

How to replace a sub-string in java of form " :[number]: "

example:

```
string="Hello:6:World"
```

After replacement,

```
HelloWorld
```

Comment: What's wrong with `:\\d+:` ?

Comment: First remove the last character if you are sure that the last one is ':' and then simply use the split() method

Comment: I want a Regular Expression for this. @Reyjohn

Comment: provide your expected output

Comment: @KhaledSaif that's what i said 18 mins ago.

Comment: I want to replace ":number:" with "" where number can be any integer
String input =":10:hello world"
String output="hello world"

Comment: You should use :\\d*: if you want to replace :: as well.

Comment: @WannaBeCoder: Why was the sentence: "I want to replace the "::" too." removed? It does not only improve the questions format but changes the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ss="hello:909:world";
```

do as below:

```
String value = ss.replaceAll("[:]*[0-9]*[:]*","");
```

Comment: just `:\\d*:` would be enough.

Comment: * is for 0 or more characters
if you want to ensure at least one character
then use + instead of *

Comment: This regexp is not correct. It replaces single standing : and numbers without surrounded by :. It would Make "Hello 5 World" as well to "Hello World". So this is what the QE wants???

Comment: + would mean that there has to be at least one : followed by at least one digit followed by at least one :

Comment: String value = ss.replaceAll(":[0-9]+:",""); would do what other commentators are saying.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to define your desired pattern

```
String pattern = "(:\d+:)";
string EXAMPLE_TEST = ':12:'
System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll(pattern, "text to replace with"));
```

should work depending on what exactly you want to replace...

Comment: did you check your pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
String s = ":6:";     
s = s.replaceAll(":", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:** After the question was changed, one should use

```
:\d+:
```

and within Java

```
:\\d+:
```

This is the answer for replacing **::** as well.

This is the regexp you should use:

```
:\d*:
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pf4S0FOUmrB4wISy)

And here is a running JavaCode snipped:

```
String str = "Hello :4: World";
String s = str.replaceAll(":\\d*:","");
System.out.println(s);
```

One problem with **replaceAll** is often, that the corrected String is **returned**. The string object from which **replaceAll** was called is not modified.

Comment: since `*` matches zero repetitions as well though this will also match `::` you should probably use `:\d+:` (one or more repetitions) depending on which is the desired behavior.

Comment: Strange. The question was edited. Before there was the sentence: "I want to replace :: as well. Hence I used *.